# Hi everyone! How can I locate the icon on the right when hovering in web flutter?

Tags: flutter, web, hover, icons

I need locate the arrow icon in the right, after the Text!

Currently when I hover, the icon blinks!!

Here is the code I try to do

```
bool showEditButton = false;
...

Stack(
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => null,
              onHover: (hovering) {
                setState(() => showEditButton = hovering);
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 50,
                width: 250,
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  'GO!',
                  maxFontSize: 18,
                  minFontSize: 8,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF001E3f),
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontSize: 18,
                      letterSpacing: 0.1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (showEditButton)
              IconButton(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                onPressed: null,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_rounded,
                  color: Color(0xFF001E40),
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
```

can anyone help me!?
i try with a AnimatedContainer but doesn't work

Comment: does `bool showEditButton = false;` outSide the build method?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh Yes it's outside

Comment: Can you include images or gif that you like to archive?

Comment: Have you tried AnimatedPositioned? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC3s2YdtWt8